# Is CakePHP on Amazon Web Services (Free Tier), a good fit?

Tags: cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a 2 GB database and a front end that will likely handle 10-15 hits during the day.  Is the AWS (with MySQL RDS) free-tier a good place to start?

Will CakePHP apps encounter time-outs or other resource issues, due to sizing of the Micro Instance?

> Micro Instance (from Amazon): Micro instances (t1.micro) provide a small amount of
>   consistent CPU resources and allow you to increase CPU capacity in
>   short bursts when additional cycles are available. They are well
>   suited for lower throughput applications and web sites that require
>   additional compute cycles periodically. You can learn more about how
>   you can use Micro instances and appropriate applications in the Amazon
>   EC2 documentation.
>
> Micro Instance 613 MiB of memory, up to 2 ECUs (for short periodic
>   bursts), EBS storage only, 32-bit or 64-bit platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only getting a very small amount of hits, you can probably run your application and mysql database on a micro instance.

The micro will be free, but you will have to pay for the RDS.

You should not notice any issues - we do most of our testing on micros, and our database is larger than yours.

Comment: BTW, RDS also has a free tier.

Answer (score 1):

It will work perfectly for your scenario.

I have deployed myself for other clients applications with at least twice requirements as yours and they worked fine.

If your application does operations saving and retrieving files from the disk I would like to suggest you giving a try to Amazon S3.